# Can an std::map be moved while iterating through it?

Tags: c++, iterator, thread-safety, stdmap

When I'm iterating through an `std::map`, is there a possibility that by for example adding an element to the map in another thread, the objects in it will be removed causing the iteration to be corrupt? (As the iterator will be pointing to a non-existing variable as it's moved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory when you add an element to an `std::map`, all the iterators in that map should stay valid. But the problem is that the operations are not atomic. If the OS suspends the inserting thread in the middle of the operation and gives control back to the iterating thread, the state of `std::map` might be invalid.

You need to synchronize access to the map via mutex or something similar. Alternatively you could use concurrency friendly collection from [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org) or another similar library. TBB provides `concurrent_unordered_map` and `concurrent_hash_map`.

Comment: a few [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx) from Microsoft PPL

Comment: Would a shared_mutex suffice? (Shared lock for reading, absolute lock for writing) I don't really know if reading from the map can cause it to maybe defragment it's objects or something like that.

Comment: Reading from the map does not modify it in any way. It's safe to do it from multiple threads. What should not be done is reading while somebody else writes into it. Writing from two threads is obviously also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

STL containers aren't thread safe. No guarantees at all. So you need to synchronize access to any standard container if they are used by different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes--if another thread may be modifying the vector, you'll need to use something like a mutex to assure that only one thread has access to the vector at any given time.

With a map, the effects of a modification are much more limited -- rather than potentially moving the entire contents of a vector, a modification only affects an individual node in the map. Nonetheless, if one thread deletes a node just as another thread is trying to read that node, bad things will happen, so you still need a mutex to assure that only one thread is operating on the map at any given time.

Comment: Is that true for `std::map` too then?